# How to make a particular string input the condition for while loop and it checks everytime an input is entered

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, user-input

*If none of these conditions are met or the output has been printed then it will return to ask the user to enter new values.
If at any point during the input stage the user enters the word "Quit" then end the program.*

Making my program follow these conditions is the only missing piece before I can solve my problem.
A while loop at the very start with the condition being as long as the string input "Quit" is entered, it will end is what I have been trying to do but keep failing on.

Our class just started and we haven't even covered methods or OOP yet. Our professor only taught us scanner system.in and the .next(datatype) methods so the other methods of the scanner class which I think has the solution I  am looking for keeps going over my head.

This is the input phase of my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please give three numbers");
        int num1 = sc.nextInt();
        int num2 = sc.nextInt();
        int num3 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Choose the temperature unit of the three numbers.");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Celsius, 2 for Fahrenheit and 3 for Kelvin");
        int tempUnit = sc.nextInt();
        switch (tempUnit) {
            case (1) -> System.out.println("Celsius was chosen.");
            case (2) -> System.out.println("Fahrenheit was chosen.");
            case (3) -> System.out.println("Kelvin was chosen.");
        }
        System.out.println("Choose the temperature unit you want to convert it into.");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Celsius, 2 for Fahrenheit and 3 for Kelvin");
        int chosenTemp = sc.nextInt();
        switch (chosenTemp) {
            case (1) -> System.out.println("Celsius was chosen.");
            case (2) -> System.out.println("Fahrenheit was chosen.");
            case (3) -> System.out.println("Kelvin was chosen.");
        }
```

I tried to come up with something with what you guys told me and this is what I came up with?

```
if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        String end = sc.nextLine();
        if (end.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {
            System.exit(0);
```

It worked but I feel like this isn't what you guys told me to do.
Can you anyone give me an example?
I read that this isn't how you set up the "Quit" condition, can anybody teach me how?

Comment: You can use [`sc.hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) to see if there is a number waiting to be read. If there is not, read it as a `String` using `sc.next()` and compare that to `"Quit"`.

Comment: "return to ask (again)" is a loop, like while/do-while. "Quit" would exit that loop. Before `nextInt` you must check whether something non-numeric was entered (like "quit"). This can be checked with `hasNextInt()`. Please write `case 1 -> ...`. Unlikely that you will come in a firm where the writing convention would be as such.

Comment: `If at any point during the input stage the user enters the word "Quit" ` - you are not set up for this and your prompts don't even suggest this.  Are the prompts specified by assignment ?  Consider how you would receive the string `Quit` .

Comment: This is my prompt. I had no idea how to set up the Quit condition so I skipped it and just did everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted achieve something as below

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Please give three numbers");
    int num1 = sc.nextInt();
    int num2 = sc.nextInt();
    int num3 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Choose the temperature unit of the three numbers.");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 for Celsius, 2 for Fahrenheit, 3 for Kelvin and 4 for Quit");

    int tempUnit = sc.nextInt();
    switch (tempUnit) {
    case 1 : 
        System.out.println("Celsius was chosen.");
        break;
    case 2 : 
        System.out.println("Fahrenheit was chosen.");
        break;
    case 3 : 
        System.out.println("Kelvin was chosen.");
        break;
    case 4 : 
        System.out.println("Quit");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```